# If $f(x)\to \infty$ the show that $\frac{1}{f(x)}\to 0$ but the converse is not always true.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $f(x)\to \infty$ the show that $\frac{1}{f(x)}\to 0$ but the converse is not always true.

Please help me by giving example for the converse part.

Comment: Here are non-examples that might help you to figure out the solution: $f(x) = x$, $f(x) = x^2$, $f(x) = x^3$, $f(x) = e^x$, $f(x) = \log x$, etc work. What is special about all of these?

Comment: $f(x) =x\sin(x)$. This has no limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: But $\dfrac1{n\sin x}$ does not tend to $0$ as $s$ tends to $\infty$$.

Comment: @ClementC. That was the idea indeed.

Comment: @ClementC. I have not yet get your point. Please elaborate

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: the inequality goes the other way.

Comment: @user1942348 I was replying to Henno Brandsma, who had a typo in his comment.

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ as $x$ tends to 0. $1/f(x)=x$ tends to 0 as x tends to 0, but $f(x)=1/x$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ as $x$ tends to 0 from right or left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}x$.

$\lvert f(x)\rvert \to +\infty$, but $f(x)$ has no limits since its sign is alterntively positive and negative. On the other hand,
$$\biggl\lvert\frac1{f(x)}\biggr\rvert=\frac1{\lvert x  \rvert}\to 0\quad\text{as}\; x\to\pm\infty,\quad \text{so}\enspace\frac1{f(x)}\to 0. $$

Comment: please give both limits

Answer (score 5):

It is true that for a function $f$ satisfying $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, we have
$$
1/f(x) \to 0 \iff 1/|f(x)| \to 0 \iff |f(x)| \to \infty
$$
So, a counterexample to the converse must satisfy $|f(x)| \to \infty$ but $f(x) \not \to \infty$.

An easy example: $f(x) = -x$ satisfies $f \to -\infty$.

Less trivially: $f(x) = x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ has no limit at infinity.

Comment: I am not understanding the easy example that you have provided. If you want to say $1/f(x)\to 0$ but $f(x)\to -\infty$ instead of being  $f(x)\to \infty$, then it is OK to me. But I need another example not like -x. Your second example is OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x\sin(x)$ obeys $\frac{1}{f(x)} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

But $f(x)$ has no limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: $\dfrac1{f(x)$ has no limit either (the denominator is periodically $0$).